# Mocking React custom hook with Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, react-hooks

I need to mock my custom hook when unit testing React component. I have read few tutorials and stackoverflow answers to this simple task, but without luck to implement it correctly.

My simplest possible setup for single test is as following:

```
// TestComponent.js

import React from "react";
import useTest from "./useTest";

const TestComponent = () => {
  const { state } = useTest("initial_value");

  return <div>{state}</div>;
};

export default TestComponent;
```

```
// useTest.jsx - simple custom hook

import React, { useState } from "react";

const useTest = (initialState) => {
  const [state] = useState(initialState);
  return { state };
};

export default useTest;
```

```
// TestComponent.test.jsx - my test case

import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import TestComponent from "./TestComponent";

jest.mock("./useTest", () => ({
  useTest: () => "mocked_value",
}));

test("rendertest", () => {
  const component = render(<TestComponent />);
  expect(component.container).toHaveTextContent("mocked_value");
});
```

So I trying to mock `useTest` custom hook to return "mocked_value", instead of "initial_value" from real custom hook. But above code just gives me this error:

```
TypeError: (0 , _useTest.default) is not a function

      3 | 
      4 | const TestComponent = () => {
    > 5 |   const { state } = useTest("initial_value");
        |                     ^
      6 | 
      7 |   return <div>{state}</div>;
      8 | };
```

I have also tried:

```
import useTest from './useTest';
// ...
jest.spyOn(useTest, "useTest").mockImplementation(() => "mocked_value");
```

```
import useTest from './useTest';
// ...
jest.spyOn(useTest, "useTest").mockReturnValue("mocked_value");
```

But both gives me error `Cannot spy the useTest property because it is not a function; undefined given instead`.

How do I implement this test?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I'm answering to myself. This way it's working:

```
jest.mock("./useTest", () => ({
  useTest: () => ({ state: 'mocked_value' }),
}));
```

And if I want to use default export in custom hook:

```
jest.mock("./useTest", () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: () => ({ state: 'mocked_value' }),
}));
```

Also, if I want to also use `setState` method in my hook and export it, I can mock it like this:

```
const mockedSetState = jest.fn();

jest.mock("./useTest", () => ({
  useTest: () => ({ state, setState: mockedSetState }),
}));
```

And now it's possible to check if `setState` has been called once:

```
expect(mockedSetState).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Answer (score 4):

For those who use the right hook it can be done this way

```
import * as useFetchMock from "../../../../hooks/useFetch";

it("should show loading component on button when state is loading", () => {
    jest.spyOn(useFetchMock, "default").mockReturnValue({
        result: null,
        message: null,
        status: "pending",
        loading: true,
        fetch: jest.fn(),
    });

    render(<Component />);

    expect.assertions(1);

    expect(screen.getByTestId(testIdComponentB)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

**import your custom hook directly and use 'default' to interact directly**

Comment: what do you mean the right hook?

Comment: this assumes your hook is a default export (`export default myHook...`). If you export by name you will not be able to use 'default'

Answer (score 2):

Since you use `export default useTest` in useTest module, it expects to get that function reference from a default attribute in your mock.

Try this:

```
jest.mock("./useTest", () => ({
  default: () => "mocked_value",
}));
```

If you want to avoid confusion, you could try `export const useTest = ...` in useTest module and then `import { useTest } from './useTest'` in your component. No need to change your test if using this approach.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but this is not working either. I tried to change "useTest" to "default" in `jest.mock` function, and also tried to export `useTest` hook with `export default useTest...`, but none is working. Always the same error `TypeError: (0 , _useTest.default) is not a function`.

Comment: I got it working by modifying it slightly (see my own answer), but thanks for this exporting tip, that was valuable!