# How to mock custom hook in react jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to mock a custom hook following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65270255/mocking-react-custom-hook-with-jest). But the **received text** from the mocked function is always coming as `undefined`.

```
Test for selected filter section › Test selected filter label                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                              
expect(element).toHaveTextContent()                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                              
Expected element to have text content:                                                                                                        
  2  filters selected                                                                                                                         
Received:
  2 undefined
```

> my-component/index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import customHook from '@path/to/customHook';

type Props = {
  checkedItems: LabelProps[];
  handleClearAll: () => void;
};

const MyComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({ checkedItems, handleClearAll }) => {
  const { content: productLabels } = customHook();

  return (
    <>
      {checkedItems.length > 0 && (
        <div data-testId="selected-filter-container">
          <div data-testId="selected-filter-lable-container">
            <p data-testId="selected-filter-label">
              {`${checkedItems.length} ${productLabels?.filtersSelected?.value}`}
            </p>
            <div data-testId="clearAll-label" onClick={handleClearAll}>
              {productLabels?.clearAll?.value}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

> my-component/index.test.tsx

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import MyComponent from './index';

const labels = {
  content: {
    clearAll: {
      key: 'data.clearAll',
      value: 'Clear all',
    },
    filtersSelected: {
      key: 'data.filtersSelected',
      value: ' filters selected',
    },
  },
};

describe('Test for selected filter section', () => {
  const checkedItemsMock = [
    {
      name: 'Mock name 1',
      slug: 'mock-slug-1',
      value: 'Mock value 1',
    },
    {
      name: 'Mock name 2',
      slug: 'mock-slug-2',
      value: 'Mock value 2',
    },
  ];
  const handleClearAllMock = jest.fn();
  const handleRemoveItemMock = jest.fn();

  jest.mock('@path/to/customHook', () => {
    return {
      // __esModule: true,

      default: () => labels,
    };
  });

  // success
  it('Test selected filter container', () => {
    render(
      <MyComponent
        checkedItems={checkedItemsMock}
        handleClearAll={handleClearAllMock}
        handleRemoveItem={handleRemoveItemMock}
      />,
    );

    const elem = screen.getByTestId('selected-filter-container');
    expect(elem).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  // success
  it('Test selected filter label container', () => {
    render(
      <MyComponent
        checkedItems={checkedItemsMock}
        handleClearAll={handleClearAllMock}
        handleRemoveItem={handleRemoveItemMock}
      />,
    );

    const elem = screen.getByTestId('selected-filter-lable-container');
    expect(elem).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  // fail
  it('Test selected filter label', () => {
    render(
      <MyComponent
        checkedItems={checkedItemsMock}
        handleClearAll={handleClearAllMock}
        handleRemoveItem={handleRemoveItemMock}
      />,
    );

    const totalReviews = `${checkedItemsMock.length} ${labels?.content?.filtersSelected?.value}`;
    expect(screen.getByTestId('selected-filter-label')).toHaveTextContent(totalReviews);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question as I have got the fix.

So I had to replace the below code

```
jest.mock('@path/to/customHook', () => {
  return {
    // __esModule: true,

    default: () => labels,
  };
});
```

with this

```
jest.mock('@path/to/customHook', () => jest.fn(() => labels));
```